# Adobe Fresco - Opening Creative Cloud Files on IPad

Tags: adobe-photoshop, ipad, adobe-bridge, adobe-fresco

I have recently installed Adobe Fresco on the IPad and am impressed with the drawing and paint features over Adobe Draw and Adobe Sketch, particularly for the Oil and Watercolor brushes.

One issue that I have not been able to work out is the syncing of files between the IPad and Windows 10 Adobe Creative Cloud (with Photoshop/Bridge). I have it all set up under a single CC account and when I go to https://assets.adobe.com/files I can see folders for "Synced Files" and "Cloud Documents".

The problem is that I can only see my files in "Synced Files" on the IPad and I can only see my files in "Cloud Documents" in Photoshop/Bridge on Windows.

I can get around this to work to some degree by Exporting and Importing files to the  "Cloud Documents" folder from Fresco and these files then become available in Photoshop/Bridge on Windows and vice versa.

What I would really like is to have a single folder that is available in both systems that automatically syncs in both directions.

If this possible, how do I set that up?

*NOTE* Please create a new [Adobe-Fresco] tag for this question, if you have the right

Comment: I did create the tag, however this is hardly a graphic design question. Please contact Adobe support with this.

Comment: Lucian - Thanks for creating the tag! I have to disagree about this not being a graphic design question. Beyond the fun we get to have being creative, our profession is all about managing good workflows. Cheers

Comment: A question does not become a graphics design question just because its about a graphics software. I might aswell ask for chair maintenance. This is simply a support question. I know that the line is diffuse but still. Adobes support can handle this question better

Answer (score 1):

I took Lucian's advice and posted to the [Adobe Fresco board](https://community.adobe.com/t5/Fresco/Adobe-Fresco-Opening-Creative-Cloud-Files-on-IPad/m-p/10662444#M487).

Adobe response summarized here:

> Adobe Cloud Documents are "in their infancy" so there will be things
>   that can be done with them in the future that can't be done right now.
>   So, currently, the only way to access both your Creative Cloud Files
>   and your Cloud Documents is either on https://assets.adobe.com or in
>   the Creative Cloud Mobile App.
>
> It sounds like what you want is to be able to see all of your
>   documents in the Creative Cloud Desktop App or in the apps (am I right
>   about that?) but it's just not possible yet.